# How to fix "Cannot allocate memory" when reading very large files?

Tags: 18.04, memory-usage

I am reading very large files and I got the following error:

```
Error: (converted from warning)  
Error in : (converted from warning)  
Error in system:  
  cannot popen 'grep processor /proc/cpuinfo 2>/dev/null | wc -l', 
  probable reason 'Cannot allocate memory'.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

as root.

Or you can try using a program that handles large files more efficiently (e.g. using mmap instead of read).

Or you can try adding more swap space.